# Connecting to skype using python skpy

Tags: python, skype

Trying to connect to `Skype` using python `Skpy API`.

Tried the below solution :

```
def connect_skype(user, pwd, token):  
    s = Skype(connect=False)  
    s.conn.setTokenFile(token)  
    try:  
        s.conn.readToken()  
    except SkypeAuthException:  
        s.conn.setUserPwd(user, pwd)  
        s.conn.getSkypeToken()  
        s.conn.writeToken()  
    finally:  
        sk = Skype(user, pwd, tokenFile=token)  
    return sk
```

This is the error:

```
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs) 
  File "C:\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests-2.21.0-py3.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests-2.21.0-py3.7.egg\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.skype.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /login/oauth/microsoft?client_id=578134&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.skype.com (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000253EF690F60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

How to resolve the Max retries exceeded issue?

Comment: and the pwd, user and token are all correct?

Comment: yes all details are correct. token is an empty text file whose path I am passing .                                               version -  SkPy-0.9,    python - 3.7.2

Comment: There's a chance that the path to login to skype has changed. I tried to access `login.skype.com` but I got redirected to `login.live.com`